# can't set UILabel text from my custom NSObject class

Tags: ios, objective-c

this is my viewController class where my label is connectd through IBOutlet and my ViewController.h is
[image]

and my ViewController.m  is[image]

and my custom class from where I want to set ViewController label text and my custom class look like this my customVC.h look like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from your example code what you're trying to accomplish. You really shouldn't be setting the label from the custom class anyway -- the view controller should be responsible for its own views. If the view controller needs information from your custom class, that class should provide the data (a string in your example), and let the controller set its own label in viewDidLoad. There's another serious problem with your code -- you're creating a new instance of ViewController with alloc init in your custom class that's not the same one you have on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the "`.label`" in your "`init`" method, do it in your "`viewDidLoad:`" method or your "`viewWillAppear:`" method.

The reason for this is because at the view controller's "`init`" time, the label and all other user interface elements haven't been loaded from the XIB or Storyboard file yet.

p.s. best practice in Objective C is to start **ALL** variables and properties with lower case letters.  So instead of "`.Label`" use "`.label`", or even better, something more descriptive, like "`.viewControllerTitleLabel`".

Comment: my custom clas is not a UIViewcontroller class

Comment: of course your customVC is not a UIViewController class, but when you call "`[viewCon.Label setText:@"hello world"];`", your ViewController hasn't been loaded yet.  You need to set the label only *after* the viewCon storyboard / XIB has loaded before you can set a label on it.  Also, why do you have a circular alloc & init pair? (customVC alloc's ViewController, and ViewController alloc's in it's viewDidLoad).

Comment: so.how do i check weather the xib is loaded and set the label's value

Comment: @vivek that is the definition of *view DID load*

Answer (score 0):

Can I see your CustomVC.h file?

I assume that your intention is to CustomVC extend the ViewController Class.

so there's need to be

```
@interface CustomVC : ViewController
```

in your CustomVC.h

then in your CustomVC.m
it should be

```
-(id)init{
   if(self = [super init]){
       [self.Label setText:@"hello world"];
  }
  return self;
}
```

you don't need to allocate the viewController object anymore.

Comment: ya I have included my customVC.h file

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to alloc - init the view controller again in your customVC class, every time you alloc init something a separate reference is provided to the object, which in this case seems to be like you are setting label text for a view controller with different reference rather than the one in which you are trying to

I suggest you to pass reference of your current view controller to your init methods like this

```
- (id)initForVC:(ViewController *)refVC
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [refVC.Label setText:@"Hello World"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Just add this function in .m file of customVC and it's definition

```
- (id)initForVC:(ViewController *)refVC;
```

in .h file

Your viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad` will change to this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    customVC *customVC = [[customVC alloc] initForVC:self];
}
```

Comment: I cannot alloc customVC *customVC = [[customVC alloc] initForVC:self]; in my viewcontroller viewdidload

Comment: I can't get you, just declare the method in you customVC.h and add the definition of that method in customVC.m file like i said in my answer, that should work

Answer (score 0):

instead of directly setting text to UILabel object create property of NSString class and set the text to that property and then then assign NSString property to UILabel, It will work.

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Sample..."];
FirstViewController *f = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
f.lbl = str; //lbl is the NSString property
[self.navigationController presentViewController:f animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and then assign lbl to UILabel object

```
lblText.text = lbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

guys I solved this by using NSNotificationcenter